# compare-object left or right side only

Tags: powershell, left-join, diff, right-join, compareobject

**Quick Question**

Is there a better (i.e. more efficient / more concise) way to do this?

```
compare-object $a $b | ?{$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}
```

**Detail**

`Compare-Object` gives paramenters `-excludeDifferent` and `-includeEqual` to allow you to amend which results you get.

- using both gives you an inner join
- using just `-includeEqual` gives you a full outer join
- using just `-excludeDifferent` is pointless; as by default equal items are excluded, so it will now exclude everything.

There are no options for `-includeLeft`, `-excludeLeft` or similar.

Currently to do a left outer join where the right side is null (i.e. items in the reference object which are not in the difference object) I need to filter the results manually, as per the code above.

Have I missed something / is there a better way?

http://ss64.com/ps/compare-object.html

Comment: Submitted feature request: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1116603/feature-suggestion-compare-object-new-parameters-referenceonly-differenceonly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no option like that for that cmdlet, however you could create a filter (in your profile for example) and then use it to filter the result :
something like

```
filter leftside{
param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [PSCustomObject]
        $obj
    )

    $obj|?{$_.sideindicator -eq '<='}

}
```

usage

```
compare-object $a $b | leftside
```

Comment: I'd not yet discovered `filter`s, so extra thanks for that pro tip!

Comment: filter was early introduced in PS but I think it could be completely replace with a `function`

Answer (score 1):

You can also add  -property SideIndicator and use an if statement for it.

```
$Missing = compare-object $Old $new -Property Name,SideIndicator
     ForEach($Grp in $Missing) {
          if($grp.sideindicator -eq "<=") {     
          # Do Something here
          }
     }
```